# Расстояние между городами

Tags: sql

Имеется база данных с городами и их координатами. Требуется вывести построчно расстояния между всеми городами БЕЗ повторов.

> Примерная база
>
> ```
> CITY_NAME   COORD_X    COORD_Y
> City1       5          10
> City2       20         30
> City3       50         70
> ```

Расстояние, например, вычисляется по формуле `COORD_X1 - COORD_X2`. Аналогично для COORD_Y.

Следует учесть, что строка с расстоянием от `City1` до `City2` это ТА ЖЕ САМАЯ строка, что и расстояние от `City2` до `City1`. Т.е. ее выводить будет не надо.

> Фактически на выходе д.б. результат:
>
> ```
> City1-City2  15   20
> City1-City3  45   60
> City2-City3  30   40
> ```

Comment: Очень интересно. Что Вы уже сделали?

Comment: И мне, и мне :) мне тоже интересно, что уже сделали? :)

Comment: Могу подсказать решение на Питоне. Нужно будет - обращайтесь)

Comment: Каждый с каждым - это _декартово произведение_ (aka `cross join` в SQL), отсечь повторения и самого на себя можно условием `City1 < City2`, остальное, думаю, сообразите.

Comment: @Igor
Сделал я немного

SELECT c1.[CITY_NAME], c2.[city_name]
      ,abs(c2.[COORD_X] - c1.[COORD_X]) as Dist_X
      ,abs(c2.[COORD_Y] - c1.[COORD_Y]) as Dist_Y
   ,row_number() over (partition BY c2.[CITY_NAME] ORDER BY c1.[CITY_NAME]) as num
  FROM [dbo].[CITIES] as c1
join cities as c2
 on c1.CITY_NAME <> c2.CITY_NAME and c2.CITY_NAME <> c1.CITY_NAME
 order by c1.CITY_NAME
Row_Number уже добавил в самый последний момент.

Comment: @i-one
По поводу CROSS JOIN. Все было бы замечательно и логично. Но, как я уже говорил, например, строка "City1 - City2" это  то же самое, что и "City2 - City1"

Comment: Можно считать по квадрату расстояния? Кривизну Земли не учитываем?

Comment: @cheops 
Дело не столько в правильности формулы :), сколько в правильности вывода строк результата. Координаты я привел для примера

Answer (score 3):

У меня нет вашей СУБД, поэтому ответ на чистом SQL (вам придется его адаптировать под свой диалект). Кроме того, чтобы воспользоваться этим решением, вам потребуется ввести в таблице CITIES первичный числовой ключ (если его еще нет). Смысл в том, чтобы воспользоваться CROSS JOIN, но сравнить первичные числовые ключи при помощи знака неравенства (больше или меньше здесь значения не имеет). Тогда в получающейся декартовой матрице, мы возьмем не все значения, а лишь треугольник под или над диагональю.

```
SELECT
  c1.CITY_NAME,
  c2.CITY_NAME,
  SQRT(ABS(c2.COORD_X - c1.COORD_X)) +
  SQRT(ABS(c2.COORD_Y - c1.COORD_Y)) as Dist_Y
FROM
  CITIES AS c1
CROSS JOIN
  CITIES AS c2
WHERE
  c1.id < c2.id
```

Comment: Вы правы. Я зашорился на простом JOIN, а в CROSS (у себя в запросе) задал дополнительное условие, которое и выдавало не верный результат.

Единственное, что я поправил в вашем коде, это

    WHERE
      c1.CITY_NAME < c2.CITY_NAME

Comment: @DmitryKh Обычный join с тем же условием должен дать тот же результат. (Они отличаются только выбираемыми столбцами в стандарте SQL. А в многих СУБД, включая mysql они вообще синонимы). Вы бы свои попытки, в виде запроса в тексте вопроса написали бы, вам минут через 5 бы помогли. По крайней мере минут через 15 уже написали что надо применять city1<city2, и это так долго тянули потому, что сообщество прочитав текст решило не отвечать ибо он слишком сильно походил на учебное задание без попыток автора к самостоятельному решению

Comment: @Mike Мой неправильный вариант с обычным JOIN я привел ниже поста. Он не дал аналогичного результата. Согласен, сразу не привел написанный код.Ввел в заблуждение сообщество :)

Comment: @Mike

    c1.CITY_NAME < c2.CITY_NAME

вместо

    c1.CITY_NAME <> c2.CITY_NAME

Но почему сработал знак "меньше" ? Как бы некий перебор значений получается?

Офф.
Почему 4 пробела перед кодом не дают сноску при форматировании?

Comment: @DmitryKh В комментариях код только в обратных апострофах работает. или вы о чем ? А знак меньше ... дано три записи 1, 2, 3. делаем join. Если `<>` то получаем 12, 13, 21, 31, 23, 32. А с меньше (или больше) только 12, 13, 23 остальные по условию не проходят

Comment: @Mike
Код работает, все замечательно! И с CROSS, и без него. Пробелы я имел в виду - выделение кода в комментариях здесь :)